# Failed to open vdpau backend - Nouveau

Tags: arch-linux, nvidia, vlc, mplayer, nouveau

I'm using ArchLinux and when I run vlc or mplayer, I used to get the error

```
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nouveau.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This doesn't seem to cause any error as far as video playback is concerned, but I want to know the reason for this problem.

I referred to [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2191669) in UbuntuForums and one of the suggestions to solve the problem was to install `nouveau-fw`. Looking at the installed files by the `nouveau-fw` package, I couldn't find `libvdpau_nouveau.so` at all in the list, but surprisingly mplayer stopped showing the error after installing the package. But `vlc` still continues to show the error.

The only other solution given in the post was to install official nvidia drivers. I'm hoping to avoid this and just use the open-source drivers. Hoping someone can provide a solution to this.

Comment: [pkgfile](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/pkgfile/) will tell you which package contains a file, in this case it's [mesa-vdpau](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/mesa-vdpau/).

Answer (score 0):

set the env variable VDPAU_DRIVER=nouveau

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).